# How to prod a new user to upvote a useful answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm becoming reluctant to answer questions from new users since they often don't upvote or accept an answer.

Frequently they will add some kind of "thanks" comment to the answer they found useful, and then disappear to use the answer without upvoting or accepting it.

It seems like the comment interface could do some simple text analysis for low reputation users, and if they are saying thanks in a comment for a question they posted, it could pop up a suggestion such as, "The proper way to thank someone on stackoverflow for an answer you found useful is to upvote or accept their answer."

I'm tempted to reply to their thanks comment with something along those lines, but that feels like begging for votes so I don't do that.

This issue comes up mostly for low volume topics, where there aren't very many people reading the tag to upvote good answers.

Comment: It already says "avoid +1 and thanks". You think we should add guidance to upvote? Note that all of these new users have read through [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/); obviously *that* didn't stick.

Comment: You don't know why they didn't upvote your post.

Answer (score 16):

> How to prod a new user to upvote a useful answer

You *don't*.

If they want to upvote an answer, they can.  If they don't, that's perfectly fine too.  You shouldn't be badgering people to give you Imaginary Internet Points.

Comment: My point was they do want to upvote the answer, they just don't understand what an upvote is. They understand when it's appropriate to say thank you, so they do that, and that's an opportunity for the system to explain things to them.

Comment: If they're under 15 rep, they can't upvote

Comment: You don't know that.  They might, they might not.  That someone says thanks for answering doesn't mean that it answered their question; plenty of people feel obligated to say thanks to *any* answer, no matter how helpful or unhelpful.  They also may not be able to, if they don't have 15 rep, are out of votes, etc.

Comment: Good point, I forgot you can't upvote until 15 rep.